# Using scrollview with child view controllers

Tags: swift, scrollview, viewcontroller

I have a main view controller (VC1) that loads various other child view controllers (VC2, VC3...) depending on what information the user needs to see.  One of the child view controllers that loads is too large for the main view.  I'm trying to incorporate a scrollview, but not having any success.  I'm honestly not even sure if the scrollview should be on VC1 or VC2.  I'm focusing on adding it within VC2, but as stated, no results.  I will try to illustrate the various layouts below.

VC1 (main view controller):

```
MainView
    ContainerView
```

VC2 (child view controller):

```
MainView
    ScrollView
        HolderView
            View1
            View2
            View3
```

VC2 is loaded into ContainerView of VC1.  VC2 is too tall vertically to display inside the ContainerView of VC1 so I need it to scroll.  Any advice?  Should the ScrollView be in VC1 instead?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what content you want to scroll.

If you want the content of VC2 to scroll *within its frame*, you could do something like this:

```
MainView
    ContainerView
        VC2.view
            ScrollView
                VC2.subView1
                VC2.subView2
                VC2.subView3
                VC2.subView ...
        VC3.view
            VC3.subView1
        VC4.view
            VC4.subView1
```

On the other hand, if you want ***all*** of the views to scroll, it would look like this:

```
MainView
    ScrollView
        StackView
            VC2.view
                VC2.subView1
                VC2.subView2
                VC2.subView3
                VC2.subView ...
            VC3.view
                VC3.subView1
            VC4.view
                VC4.subView1
```